# Why won't this text align next to image properly? Can't get a horizontal screen alignment either

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

There is probably an answer out there but, clearly I'm not grasping it so I'm coming here for a further explanation and assistance. CSS is freakin complex af, lol Fantastic, right? Here's a screenshot of the my current project:
[image]

Two questions: First, why is the first text under the image and the rest beside the image? That's just a general inquiry, its not at all how I want to you have it displayed. Which brings me to question two...

Second, I am struggling with the whole `display: inline-block` property concept. I want these displayed horizontally with the text beneath not beside.

Here's the code specifically for the provided screenshot:

```
<div className={styles.grid}>
 <a href="..\pages\satweather.js">
  <img
   className={styles.img}
   src="weatherbutton.jpg"
   width="100"
   height="50"
   onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"> 
  </img>
  <div>&rarr; SatWeather</div>
 </a>
 <a href="..\pages\satsecurity.js">
  <img
   className={styles.img}
   src="securitybutton.jpg"
   width="100"
   height="50"
   onClick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"
  ></img>
  <div className={styles.imbutton}>&rarr; SatSecurity</div>
 </a>
 <a href="..\pages\photovideo.js">
  <img
   className={styles.img}
   src="satbutton.jpg"
   width="100"
   height="50"
   onClick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"
  ></img>
  <div className={styles.imbutton}>&rarr; Photo/Video</div>
 </a>
 <a href="..\pages\satagriculture.js">
  <img
   className={styles.img}
   src="farmbutton.jpg"
   width="100"
   height="50"
   onClick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"
  ></img>
  <div className={styles.imbutton}>&rarr; SatAgriculture</div>
 </a>
 <a href="..\pages\satanimal.js">
  <img
   className={styles.img}
   src="animalbutton.jpg"
   width="100"
   height="50"
   onClick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"
  ></img>
  <div className={styles.imbutton}>&rarr; SatAnimal</div>
 </a>
</div>
```

The referenced CSS - as it currently stands, is as follows:

```
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}

.imbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px; 
}
```

I've tried dozens of variations from `display: flex;` to `display: block;` on parent and `display: inline-block;` on child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your anchor tags have `display: flex` to force your image and description into a single row, so a lot of the other css is unnecessary. Flex-wrap will allow your content to expand to other rows if it overflows. Horizontal scrolling will happen on smaller screen sizes without this.

Here is the final result:

```
.img {
  margin: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* max-width: 800px; */
}
  
.grid a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Adding a max-width to the container will cause flexbox to wrap the content.

Comment: Fantastic! Appreciate it. But now how do I get it to run horizontally instead of vertically? Grid doesn't seem like the best option. Assume to keep it, or is there a better option?

Comment: @HiB I updated the css to allow the content to flow horizontally and overflow vertically if needed. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oooohhh, ```flex-wrap``` all my search, hadn't come across that property. CSS so extensive! I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question for you, or anyone else tho: Will this be maintained upon implementing mobile viewpoint? Or if I finally break down and decide to use Tailwind CSS on the project?