# Why can't I get these images with titles to flow horizontally center?

Tags: javascript, css

Previously I posed a question here[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998066/why-wont-this-text-align-next-to-image-properly-cant-get-a-horizontal-screen/72998225#72998225), and it was answered appropriately to solve my first issue but not my second issue - the first being proper code arrangement and the second being the question I'm talking about. I removed the CSS code that was originally applied, which you can view on original question, and applied the new CSS code as follows:

```
.img {
  margin: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* max-width: 800px; */
}
  
.grid a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I removed the `max-width: 800px;` and received the following result[image: Minimized screen view][image: Full Screen View].

Adding the `max-width: 800px;` showed the same results in image. Tried various combinations of CSS with no positive results. The code snippet as follows:

```
<div className={styles.grid}>
          <div className={styles.imgc}>
          <a href="..\pages\satweather.js">
            <img
              className={styles.img}
              src="weatherbutton.jpg"
              width="100"
              height="50"
              onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"> 
            </img>
            <div>&rarr; SatWeather</div>
          </a>
          </div>

/* code continues in repetition for 4 more images 
before ending with */

</div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I might try or a solution to this problem? To get these images aligned center and horizontally to the page. Help is appreciated.

Here is desired result, but without space between photo and link to page
[image: desired result]

Please Note: This is JS, not HTML.

Comment: can you create a Codepen or any other reproduction for this and maybe an image or design for the expected result?

Comment: Added desired result above..

Comment: Also went back and added a <div> around each image as a way to pair the image with the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here is `html` version of your code.
- Use `display:flex` to image container and then, Make one separate element for image box just like here which is `image-box` set it's `anchor` tag to `display:flex` and `align-items:center`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #050505;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-class {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image-box a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="image-box">
      <a href="javasctipt:void(0);">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="image" class="image-class">
        <h1>image titel</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-box">
      <a href="javasctipt:void(0);">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="image" class="image-class">
        <h1>image titel</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-box">
      <a href="javasctipt:void(0);">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="image" class="image-class">
        <h1>image titel</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-box">
      <a href="javasctipt:void(0);">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="image" class="image-class">
        <h1>image titel</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is closer, but not quite what I'm looking for. The issue:

```flex-direction: horizontal;``` is what I needed, not ```flex-direction: column;```. Also, it applies only to full screen. I need it to apply when minimized too.  Good start tho, so thanks!

I will continue to fiddle. Also should not this is HTML and I need JS. Didn't specify so that's my fault.

Comment: You can check it now make sure to **view in fullscreen with**